# iOS Show detail segue not working when SplitViewController is subview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Hey so I have been trying to implement an ad banner view below the split view controller of my app. I managed to do it by creating a `BannerViewController`, which resizes the splitViewController and places the banner at the bottom, which works. However, now I notice that tapping an item in the list in the TableViewController doesn't work on iPhone. It stays selected like on iPad, so it must think it is on iPad and has to display the detail next to the master. The segue is hooked up in Interface Builder from the UITableViewCell to the navigation controller of the detail view. And it was all working fine even for a while after implementing the banner controller, but just stopped this morning.

I have tried calling performSegue in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, and `prepareForSegue` is called every time but usually does not show anything on iPhone.
Here is `BannerViewController`:

```
class BannerViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {

    var bannerView = GADBannerView()
    var showingBanner = false

    var contentView, bannVC: UIView!

    var originalFrame: CGRect!

    init(contentVC: UIViewController) {
        contentView = contentVC.view
        originalFrame = contentView.frame // Store the original frame of the content view for later use

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        // If banner is hidden, position off screen (x > window.height) and make contentView size of window
        view.addSubview(contentView)

        // Create banner view
        setupAds()

    }

    // Required init, just call super
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    // Update the position of the banner on the screen
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        bannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: contentView.frame.size.height, width: contentView.frame.size.width, height: 50)
    }

    // MARK: - Adverts

    // Checks if ads have been disabled by buying the in app purchase
    func checkAdsDisabled() -> Bool {
        return Product.findBy(identifier: ProductRepo.DisableAds)?.purchased ?? false
    }

    func setupAds() {
        if (!checkAdsDisabled()) {
            // Ads have not been disabled, set them up
            bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-123456/xyz"
            bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            bannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait
            bannerView.delegate = self
            bannerView.rootViewController = self

            let request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
            request.testDevices = ["xyz"] // My iPhone
            bannerView.load(request)

            // Initially position off screen
            view.addSubview(bannerView)
            hideBanner()
        }
    }

    // Hide banner and update view positions
    func hideBanner() {
        contentView.frame.size.height = originalFrame.size.height
        view.layoutSubviews()
        showingBanner = false
    }

    // Show banner and update view positions
    // Called by adViewDidReceiveAd
    func showBanner() {
        contentView.frame.size.height = contentView.superview!.frame.size.height - bannerView.frame.size.height
        view.layoutSubviews()
        showingBanner = true
    }

    // MARK: - GADBannerViewDelegate

    /// Tells the delegate an ad request loaded an ad.
    func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView!) {
        print("adViewDidReceiveAd: Banner loaded")
        if !showingBanner{
            showBanner()
        }
    }
}
```

If it helps, also I am using SearchController in the master view. When tapping the search bar I get the warning `Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged`, which may be related, but I can't get any info out of that.